# Combining Html5 Games (like Webview canvas) into adobe flash/animate

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, merge, construct-2

I have a special question about merging two projects into one project, basically made with differend engines.

I made a project with flash/animate years ago. Currently iam working with construct2. In flash, there is the possability to include websites with webview canvas. Would it be possible, to create a game in construct2, export it as html5 project, and show/include it inside my flash application? So i wouldnt have to create it twice with differend engines?

it would be awesome, if i could include the local html5 game (construct2) into my adobe flash/animate game.

The game should be placed inside the project environment, so you wouldnt need to have internet connection. thats the requirement.

(This is just an idea, iam not sure if its possible, thats why iam asking here, before i would have to create the same game ive made in construct2 also in as3.)

Thank you very much for your answer! Iam excited for your inputs,

cheers!

Comment: I understand you can create html5 projects in Animate now. Would that work, or do you need an actual swf?

Comment: @KyleDelaney hey! Thanks for your reply! Yea it would be great, if you could show me an swf. So do you think i could include a html5 project straight into my animate project? Iam very excited!

Comment: I'm not sure you answered my question.